# algorithms 3 jar problem running time

Tags: algorithms

I had a test in algorithms and data structure. My professor and I got into an argument about this question. you have 3 jug n1,n2,n3 and each one start with s1,s2,s3 liters of water.
And you have a big infinite jug, k1, k2, and so on, to store water. You are given a number m, and you want to find out if it is possible to fill one of the infinite jugs with m liters of water.
He said you must check for each number n^2, so the running time will be n^3.
I don't see it this way, and I am not sure I am right. If you can, please tell me if my way is right.
My way is like that.

```
def findDP(n1,n2,s1,s2) -> dict:
   options = {} # the key shows us the number available, and the value is the number of steps to get to this number
   # here is a code that finds the option for two jugs
   # here is a for loop that starts from 1 until m and checks for each number 
   # the following condition
   for I in range(1, m):
      isValidVol = False
      currentAction = inf
      for key, val in options:
         complementary = I - k
         if prev<0: continue;
         if prev in options:
             # calc the number of steps
             currentAction = min(currentAction, options[prev] + options[key])
             isValidVol = True # cause there is valid volume
         
         if validVol:
            options[i] = currentAction

          
   return options

def findDP3(n1,n2,n3,s1,s2,s3,m)-> dict:
   options = {...findDP(n1,n2,s1,s2), ...findDP(n1,n3,s1,s3), ...findDP(n2,n3,s2,s3)}
   # of course, you only choose the minimum
   for I in range(1, m):
      isValidVol = False
      currentAction = inf
      for key, val in options:
         complementary = I - k
         if prev<0: continue;
         if prev in options:
             # calc the number of steps
             currentAction = min(currentAction, options[prev] + options[key])
             isValidVol = True # cause there is valid volume
         
         if validVol:
            options[i] = currentAction
```

It is run's in o(n^2) cause only three times running the findDP.
I am not sure if it is 100% right. I will be happy if someone can tell me if I am wrong.
He says you have to check manually all the options, which will take o(n^3).
When I say n, I mean n as running time, just semantic instead of m.
You can only fill the jar to be complete, pore the water from jar x to jar y until jar y is complete or until jar x is empty. Empty the jar.
summary rules:

1. Empty a Jug
2. Fill a Jug
3. Pour water from one jug to the other until one of the jugs is either empty or full.

This question is the same as in[here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-water-jug-puzzle/.), but instead of two jars, there are 3, and each jar starts with some constant amount of water s1,s2,s3. We just want to say if we can create m liters and if so in how many steps.

Comment: What is $n$?  You haven't defined it.  If $n_1,n_2$ are coprime you can make all volumes greater than $n_1n_2-n_1-n_2-1$  See the [coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem)

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: When I say n, I mean running time the same as m.

Comment: From the limited description of the problem given so far, I would say you can put any number of liters $\le s_1 + s_2 + s_3$ into one of the large jugs. You haven't mentioned any restrictions on what you can do, so just pour in the necessary number of liters. You listed $n_1, n_2, n_3$, but didn't mention what these numbers represent. Ross Millikan made a number of assumptions to say as much as he did. Those assumptions are likely correct, but it would be better if you actually gave us a comprehensible description instead of making us guess what you mean.

Comment: You are right; I filled in the rules the same as in https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/two-water-jug-puzzle/, but with three jars, each jar starts with some water.